# Android Emulator - camera error - can't connect to camera

Tags: android, camera, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to use the camera on an android emulator to test sth., but it just doesn't work. I always get the can't connect to camera error. I tried all settings and every solution I found so far didn't work for me.

[Camera Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSUdq.png)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You add permission in androidmanifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```